# Restarting HAProxy with -st flag returns error

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy, ubuntu-14.04, cat

I'm restarting HAproxy (on Ubuntu Server x64 14.04) with the following command

```
haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -st $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)
```

However, when actually executing this command, I get the following error

```
cat: /var/run/haproxy.pid: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody shed some light into the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

The `/var/run/haproxy.pid` file does not exist. There could be several reasons for that.

- `haproxy` is not running at all
- the pidfile got los
- `haproxy` writes no pidfile at all
- `haproxy` is configured to store the pidfile at a different location